# "Unable to create new image" WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

This problem looks like it's not had a clear solution as yet. I have installed a clean version of WordPress via SSH with folder permissions set to 755 and file permissions to 644.

I have no problem uploading images, updated plugins etc, but when it comes to editing an image I receive this error:

[image]

WP_DEBUG shows nothing, and there are no other errors on the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem here, I forgot to install gd with php...
Install it fix the problem :

```
sudo apt install php7.2-gd
```

Answer (score 5):

The most likely reason is not having `mod-gd` installed.

WordPress uses the GD Graphic Library to manipulate images (see `wp-admin/includes/image.php`), and this error appears when it is not installed.

It can also be caused by whitespace introduced somewhere. Check for any php closing tags `?>` and remove them. They should not be used because whitespace can be introduced after them.

Comment: I have the php7.2-gd library installed. I is listed in phpinfo(). I am still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I tried to restore image after scaling and the max size was below the original image size. I couldn't change max size but found copy of my image on google and just replaced it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working online with a hosting company and have cpanel as your hosting platform you can enable this module in Cpanel through
PHP Selector---> extensions---> gd .

See pictures bellow

[Cpanel ( PHP Selector)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Pns.jpg)

[extensions --> gd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAgKo.jpg)

Comment: This might not work on OP's use case (cpanel installed?). Pls explain what OP has to do, in order to get his problem solved.

Comment: IF you are using cpanel you can enable this extension only from this menu, as usually don't have access with ssh to install or update anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check you PHP version

```
$ apt list --installed | grep php
```

Then install the GD version

```
$ sudo apt install phpX.X-gd
```

For example

```
$ sudo apt install php8.1-gd
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I managed to solve the problem as follows:

- I accessed the **PHP.ini** file by opening in Notepad
- I searched for '**gd**' (without quotes) and removed the '**;**' (without quotes) from the beginning of the word 'extension=gd'